# WMS OpenLayers filter for date

Tags: openlayers, wms, wms-time

I need to filter the WMS layer included in my map for a date field. Basically I only want to show what has happened after a certain date:

I tried the following, but no luck

```
createMap = () => {

    addCommonProjections();
    const vectorSource = new VectorSource();


    const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
        source: vectorSource
    });


    const baseLayer = new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM()
    });

    this.wms_source = new ImageWMS({
        url: environment.live_lightning_data,
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        styles: 'default',
        params: {
            layers: '0'
        },
    });

    const lightning_layer = new ImageLayer({});
    this.map = new Map({
        layers: [baseLayer, lightning_layer],
        target: document.getElementById('lightning'),
        view: new View({
            center: fromLonLat([175.79, -37.79]),
            zoom: 7,
            projection: 'EPSG:3857'
        })
    });

    lightning_layer.filter.greaterThan('data_date_time', '2019/03/02');
    lightning_layer.setSource(this.wms_source);
```

I know, a little chaotic, but the map map itself displays the data correctly, but it is unhappy with however I try to add the filer.

The way I added it now,results in '... is not a function'

Anyone any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide full error message.

Comment: What if you add TIME: 'your-time' as one of the params ?

Comment: Not sure how you can filter an image (the result of the WMS GetMap request); you need to ask the service for the data, using the appropriate request params.